# Keeping New and Old Ipads

Tags: ipad

My wife gave me a new IPad for Christmas. I want to keep the other Ipad for the use of my 6 year old daughter that has countless games on that Ipad. How I can keep applications that interest me (like QuickOffice Pro) of my old Ipad and leave the rest of the applications on the old Ipad to my daughter?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to back up the old iPad to iCloud or your computer using iTunes.

Then restore the old backup onto the new iPad Air (you need to erase all content and settings to get the device clean for the restore).

When the setup asks if you have a backup, load that on the new device.

- delete all apps and settings on the old iPad that should not be there.
- delete all apps and settings from the new iPad that should not be there.

At that point, you can use the two separately. Look to perhaps turn off automatic downloads. At some point you can wipe the old iPad and let your daughter start buying her own apps or split things with a mix of the old Apple ID and her new Apple ID as well - you can mix purchases unlike iCloud settings.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have a valid backup before you follow my steps.

if you have iOS 7 or any type of iOS here's what you can do, format the ipad drive : http://techchannel.radioshack.com/format-ipad-1036.html

You can also do another way to format the IPAD. Go to your General Settings. You should find a option that says "Reset Phone", tap on that and tap "Delete Everything" known as format.

**Check out this blog for more help : http://www.padgadget.com/2010/06/14/ipad-quick-tip-%E2%80%93-reboot-reset-format-your-ipad/**